# Multithreading - Stop Creating thread if some condition meet in worker function

Tags: python, multithreading

I am scraping the content from web where each page has different url. But, there is no way to get the total number of
pages. So, I am iterating until url is valid.
For that I created infinite thread in below program. But, I want to stop creating thread if url is not valid.

```
        def worker(page_no):
            
            ## do something
            r = requests.get('www.xyz.com'+'?'+str(page_no))
            
            if some-condition satisfied:
                stop creating threads.
                
        def main():    
            with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                 # infinite input sequence
                 input_sequence = itertools.count(1)
                 # create threads
                 res = executor.map(worker, input_sequence)
```

Expected:

If condition meet in worker, all the threads created before that threads should be executed properly and no more threads should be created. executor.map should stop processing input sequence.

Answer (score 0):

First:

Most probably the creation of workers (threads) is faster than the execution of the workers. This means that in any case we somehow have to manually limit the worker creation.

For this, in a first attempt I'm going to manually count and create the workers instead of using an iterator.

Second:

The workers need a mutable object to signal the outer world that they have found the stop condition.

I'm going to create a simple class for this.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
from time import sleep


class Stopper(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False


class Worker(object):

    def __init__(self, stopper):
        self.stopper = stopper

    # This method is called when the worker is executed.
    def __call__(self, page_no):

        # Don't do anything if stop condition was found by another worker.
        # I'm not sure if you want this.
        if self.stopper.stop:
            print("Skip already generated job %d" % page_no)
            return

        # Simulate some work
        for i in range(4):
            print("page: %d  - %d" % (page_no, i))
            if page_no == 29 and i == 2:  # This is our stop condition.
                self.stopper.stop = True  # Only one thread should do this!
                print("!!!!!!!!    Found    !!!!!!!!")
            sleep(0.5)


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

        # Use this object to communicate
        stopper = Stopper()

        # create threads
        page = 1
        pages_simultaneous = 25

        while not stopper.stop:
            jobs = []
            page_max = page + pages_simultaneous
            while page < page_max:
                page += 1
                jobs.append(executor.submit(Worker(stopper), page))
            wait(jobs)  # Limit the number of simultaneously created workers.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to use an iterator, you can write an iterator class which also takes the stopper in its `__init__` and does `raise StopIteration` on `stopper.stop`. But still, you have to manually limit the number of simultaneously created workers.